# Time difference between two varchar datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use the datediff function to get the time difference in seconds between two date time values which are in the varchar format. Following is my query which is giving me the error.

```
DATEDIFF(second, CONVERT(Datetime, data_deviceTransactions_createdTime, 120), CONVERT(Datetime, data_deviceTransactions_updatedTime, 120))
```

data_deviceTransactions_createdTime and data_deviceTransactions_updatedTime are varchar values,

Comment: please give me Error message.

Comment: Error message is - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: Which type date time you pass in " data_deviceTransactions_createdTime "

Comment: Eg:- Thu, 20 Sep 2018 05:54:30 GMT. This is in varchar.

Comment: "date time values which are in the varchar format." There's your problem right there. Do not store `datetime` values as `varchar`. store them as `datetime2` and let go of all the problems you currently have with this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING('Thu, 20 Sep 2018 05:54:30 GMT', 5, LEN('Thu, 20 Sep 2018 05:54:30 GMT') - 8), 113)
```

This should return **2018-09-20 05:54:30.000**

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(second, CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(data_deviceTransactions_createdTime, 5, LEN(data_deviceTransactions_createdTime) - 8), 113), CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(data_deviceTransactions_updatedTime, 5, LEN(data_deviceTransactions_updatedTime) - 8), 113))
```